# How do I create a scatterplot in python to depict vectors within a given output?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi im new to python and trying to learn plot viz

I have an output from my dataframe:

```
df.groupby('Type').mean()
Out[29]: 
        Rating        Reviews       Size      Installs
Type                                                  
Free  4.167469  269978.303527  35.166263  7.720880e+06
Paid  4.252677    5612.005525  58.776243  6.588497e+04
```

I want to create a scatterplot showing size and rating of apps for both paid and free apps

My input:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(['Rating'],['Size'])
```

I want rating to be my x and size to be my y plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: `df.plot`**

```py
df.plot('Rating', 'Size', kind='scatter')
```

or

```py
df.plot.scatter('Rating', 'Size')
```

**Method 2: `matplotlib`**

```py
plt.scatter(df['Rating'], df['Size'])
```

or

```py
plt.plot(df['Rating'], df['Size'], '.')
```